# unable to print euro symbol in a "C" program

Tags: c, character-encoding, windows-console, euro

I am unable to print the euro symbol. The program I am using is below.

I have set the character set to [codepage 1250](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305143.aspx) which has 0x80 standing for the euro symbol.

Program
=======

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Current locale is: %s\n", setlocale (LC_ALL, ".1250"));
    printf("Euro character: %c\n", 0x80);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output
======
Current locale is: English_India.1250
Euro character: ?

Other details
=============
OS: Windows Vista
Compiler: vc++ 2008 express edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this:
http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/eurodos.html

There are sections, which could help you a lot:

- Display the euro-symbol in full-screen DOS and command consoles in Windows NT, 2000, or XP
- Display the euro symbol in DOS and command console windows in Windows 2000 and XP (built-in support for TrueType fonts)
- Display the euro in DOS and command consoles in Windows 2000 and XP (bitmap and TrueType fonts)

Comment: This is the correct answer, the console font has to be changed.  In addition, you must call SetConsoleCP() to switch the console code page, setlocale() does not do this.

Comment: Thanks. 

You have to set the console's input and output code page. i.e SetConsoleCP(), SetOutputConsoleCP().

Refer to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683169%28VS.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686013%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

the 0x80 char is falsely stated as the euro sign, it is the Padding Char.
See here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28263

If I remember correctly it must something around 0x120, try printing in a for loop from 120 to 130

Comment: The 0x80 code for the euro sign is correct in windows 1250 and windows 1252 code pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("\u20AC");
return 0;
}
```

I used GCC compiler and this works fine. The output is: €

---

This only work with C++ and C99

Comment: I wanted to print '€' using a non-unicode character set.

The issue was with the windows console as pointed out by SLA80 above. 

Thanks anyway.