# Python wrong output of currency symbol on server

Tags: python, utf-8, windows-server-2008

I want to display currencies using a really simple python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('€')
```

On my local computer, everything works fine when I run the script with powershell.

If I run the same script on my Windows Server 2008 however, the output is a question mark (`?`).

I tried all solutions from this answer without success: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39936499/4437149.

Since im new to python I cant figure out whats exactly wrong.

Is there something missing in my script or any server misconfiguration? Im using the newest version of python (currently 3.8.0).

Comment: Your terminal does not support or is not set to UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Setting the terminal font to "`Lucida Console`" seems to be the solution.

---

**Old Answer:**

On windows, you may want to use an escape sequence (aka Python source code, aka code point), i.e.:

```
print("\u20AC") # Euro
print("\u0024") # Dollar
print("\u00A3") # Pound
print("\u00A5") # Yen
```

---

```
€
$
£
¥
```

---

References:

- http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/eurodos.html
- [unable to print euro symbol in a "C" program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969385/unable-to-print-euro-symbol-in-a-c-program)
- https://lwn.net/Articles/741698/

Comment: The solution was to set the font of the terminal to "Lucida Console". Then the characters showed up with your example above.

Comment: Glad you sorted out!