# How to output € symbol in C?

Tags: c, character-encoding, printf, clion

I don't know how to output the Euro symbol in a C99 Project, I am using CLion to develop the project and I'm using MinGW as Toolchain (I don't know if that matters).

I already searched a lot and I can't find any answer to my problem, hope someone can help me.

I already tried to do this

```
printf("€");
printf("\u20AC");
```

The output is `Ôé¼`, but I'm expecting `€`.

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: this is what I get "Ôé¼"

Comment: where are you seeing that output? (terminal, some GUI...?)

Comment: @bool3max like I said I am using CLion, the output and input is on CLion "Terminal"

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969385/unable-to-print-euro-symbol-in-a-c-program

Comment: On the bottom of your screen there should be the current file encoding. Is it set to UTF-8 or something like ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @Martin Fink   The file encoding is UTF-8

Comment: Try `printf("\xE2\x82\xAC");` Those 3 bytes represent the euro symbol in the UTF-8 encoding. Though the code in your question should produce the desired result.

Comment: @Saucy Goat I already read that post and I didn't understand...

Comment: That's what I have on my machine too, but I am able to print the symbol there. The problem then is probably that the CLion terminal is set to the wrong encoding. If you execute your program on a terminal that is configured to use UTF-8, your code *should* work right.

Comment: @bool3max the output is still the same

Comment: @MartinFink how can I change the terminal ?

Comment: Well then your encoding is wrong. Try to set the encoding of the *terminal*, not the file.

Comment: See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-output-encoding.html

Comment: @bool3max just did that and tried again with "\xE2\x82\xAC" and "\u20AC" the output is the same as before...

Comment: Out of ideas then. Try to run your executable and pipe its output to a utility such as `hexdump` or `xxd` to make sure that the correct bytes are coming out. e.g. `./yourapp | hexdump`.

Comment: Normally C outputs strings with the "C" `locale`. A first step on how to set up another `locale` for multibyte characters can be found here in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039815/print-utf-8-multibyte-character-in-c, but depending on your setting there might be more to it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is using the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as native encoding.
Just print like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\xE2\x82\xAC");

    return 0;
}
```

You can find a useful link to Euro Sign [here](https://eurosymbol.eu/ascii-code)

Comment: Read the comments.